# EOSJS - error message when eos.transfer(..)

Tags: eosjs

When I try to call eos.transfer(..) I'm getting this error

```
{ message: 'assertion failure with message: unable to find key',
file: 'wasm_interface.cpp',
line_number: 930,
method: 'eosio_assert' }
```

That is the code:

```
Eos = require('eosjs')

config = {
    chainId: '038f4b0fc8ff18a4f0842a8f0564611f6e96e8535901dd45e43ac8691a1c4dca', 
    keyProvider: ['key1','key2'],
    httpEndpoint: 'http://dev.cryptolions.io:38888',
    expireInSeconds: 60,
    broadcast: true,
    verbose: false, 
    sign: true
  }

eos = Eos(config)

eos.transfer('token', 'wallet', '1.0000 TKN', '', (error, result) => {console.log(result)})
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: are you using correct keys? and also the keys are imported in your wallet?

Comment: Yes I'm using correct keys, keys are imported and account is broadcasted to jungle testnet.

Comment: unable find key often means that the token or the user is not on the chain

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution. I guess that there is problem in EOSJS

```
eos
 .transaction({
   actions: [
     {
       account: “tokencontract”,
       name: “transfer”,
       authorization: [
         {
           actor: “senderaccount”,
           permission: “active”
         }
       ],
       data: {
         from: “senderaccount”,
         to: “receiveraccount”,
         quantity: `5.0000 TKN`,
         memo: “some description of the transaction”
       }
     }
   ]
 })
```

Comment: btw I haven't changed config file.